# Ldap and user groups (Require ldap-group)

Tags: web2py

I am developing a APP  and I would like to use this APP with our LDAP
and filter the users by groups. I have this code in APACHE:

```
           AuthLDAPURL ldap://localhost/ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com?uid
           AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
           AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
           AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
           Require ldap-group cn=developer,cn=testers,cn=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
```

It works fine. Only people from the list developer and tester can get
inside this area. I am trying to do the same in Web2py, but I can not
make a filter from the groups

I have this code and is working ok without groups:

```
auth.settings.login_methods=[ldap_auth(mode='uid_r',server='localhost',port='389',
base_dn='ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com', filterstr='objectClass=*')]
```

I not sure how to use: Require ldap-group in web2py.

Anyone can help me?

In advance many thanks

Comment: Here there is nice slice: 
http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1476/ldap-auth-with-allowed-groups-and-manage-groups.

I did'nttest yet

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrestling with this myself. I think the solution is to import the groups from LDAP by doing some LDAP queries.

The bad part with this approach is that it requires you to (1) insert groups into web2py auth_group tables when the use FIRST logs in. (2) It would require maintenance of the groups if they tend to change. This could be done with a cron job or manually.

You can find out if the user has logged in before like this:

```
query = (db.auth_event.description.like('%Logged-in%'))&(db.auth_event.user_id==auth.user.id)

if db(query).count() == 1:
  # Query LDAP for group membership, update auth_group table
```

Here is some example code for an LDAP query - this one is based off of just looking up user info (I'm not sure how LDAP organizes groups - I will be writing code to extract groups in a week or two):
    import ldap
    from ldap.filter import filter_format as ff

```
ldap_attrs = ['sn','givenName','telephoneNumber', 'mail' ]

FILTER_TPL = '(&%s(objectclass=i3person))'
sch = ff('(%s=%s)', ('uid', auth.user.username))

ldap_filter = FILTER_TPL % sch
con = ldap.initialize("ldap://YOUR-LDAP-SERVER")
dn= "YOUR-DN-FOR-USERS/GROUPS"
mode = "uid"
port = 389
ldap_results = con.search_s(dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, ldap_filter, ldap_attrs)

dn, res = ldap_results[0]
```

You can get more info on python's ldap here:
http://www.python-ldap.org/docs.shtml

(this one has code examples related to querying groups)
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ldap_crud/

Also, DON'T forget to use filter_format (imported as ff above), it will escape your ldap queries preventing LDAP injection if any user input is allowed to make it to the code. For my purposes, I was making a publicly accessible form that searched LDAP entries for people.

Here is a posting on mirroring ActiveDirectory Groups into LDAP groups. I'm posting this because while it does the opposite, some of it is still useful, particularly the filter for getting groups from LDAP since that's the same whether reading or writing, and it uses python-ldap:
http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mirorring_Active_Directory_user_acconts_in_LDAP

If your ldap groups don't change much, you could create a script that does the following:

- Delete all group membership for web2py accounts (start fresh).
- For each account, query ldap for groups

  - For each query, extract all the groups.
  - Copy the groups into auth_groups if not exists
  - Add member to group (auth_membership or something?)

Then just run the script on an as-needed basis. I like to delete things when running ETL scripts like this because then you start fresh and don't duplicate things or run into errors when things already exist and violate DB constraints.

Comment: First of all many thanks,

For now, I have created the group structure inside my database, so:

1- I login in Ldap
2- (if yes) I check the group in my database